# Baseline and entry in memory overhead table in https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Memory-overhead/334087984d6c16a1491ecfeb4c9387663ad56fa2

Tags: caffeine-cache, memory-overhead

Can someone explain what does baseline and entry mean as mentioned in tables in https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Memory-overhead/334087984d6c16a1491ecfeb4c9387663ad56fa2?

Comment: `Baseline` is the overhead of the empty cache while `Entry` is the incremental overhead for each addition.